# Change validation color in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am validating my forms by using this:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    UnitName: [this.editUnit.UnitName, Validators.required],
    Area:     [this.editUnit.Area, Validators.required],
    OwnerId: [this.editUnit.OwnerId],
    IsWithParking: [this.editUnit.IsWithParking],
    ParkingArea: [this.editUnit.ParkingArea],
});
```

and this is to implement it in the html form

```
<mat-card style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <mat-card-content>
      <form [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="UnitName" placeholder="Unit Name">
            <mat-error *ngIf="UnitName.invalid" style="color: red;">{{unitNameError()}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput formControlName="Area" placeholder="Unit Area">
            <mat-error *ngIf="UnitName.invalid" style="color: red;">{{areaError()}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Unit Owner" formControlName="OwnerId">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let p of persons" [value]="p.PersonId">
                {{p.FirstName}} {{p.MiddleName}} {{p.LastName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error *ngIf="OwnerId.invalid" style="color: red;">{{ownerIdError()}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="IsWithParking" placeholder="With Parking">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let y of yesNo" [value]="y.value">
                {{y.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Parking Area Size" formControlName="ParkingArea">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateUnit()" [disabled]="form.invalid">
          Update Unit
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="cancel()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </form>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

and this is the result on initial load:
[image]

As you can see in the image, without doing anything yet, the required input fields have default  color in the line and font but for those input fields that does not have a required attribute, its line color and font is green. And as soon as I start filling in the required input fields, I get the line and font color green as well. Is there a way to change this green colors? It really doesn't match the red theme color that I have. Thank you very much.

Comment: No, Don't create a "StackBlitz" — create a local "Stack Snippet" -- it is the _page with <>_ icon when you're writing/editing a question. I would downvote @SiddAjmera 's comment if that were possible.

Comment: @StephenP - Can a Stack Overflow code snippet run Angular code, and include Material components?

Comment: @StephenP, any specific reason for your suggestion?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, no it can't. It only has support for AngularJS and NOT Angular. That's why I suggested creating a StackBlitz. I've already done most of it in the one I mentioned. Just including the relevant styles would help replicating the issue.

Comment: @SiddAjmera & ConnorsFan - I may have been hasty in this _particular_ case... Stack snippets can include quite a number of frameworks, including AngularJS, and can include other things by importing via a script tag, but indeed I did not check on "plain" Angular as I haven't used it. While I do maintain that a stack snippet is _preferable_ I apologize and concede that it may not always be the best available option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) to render the form, you might want to look into [defining a custom Angular Material theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme) (or [re-theming components on an individual basis](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#theming-only-certain-components)).